# How do I get user to only borrow copies of books and not review?

Tags: class, oop, object, inheritance, uml

so am working on a library managment system and  i  have this document class that can be of book(livre) type or review(revue), each document has few copies and the user is only allowed to borrow copies of books and not those of  reviews, i couldn't find any other way than  make two copy(exemplaire) classes one for book and other for review. 
Thanks in advance.

[image: class diagram of library]

Comment: why not adding a Boolean attribute (Canbeborrowed)?

Comment: thanks yahya, i had this idea but isn't that going to ruin the meaning of the association (borrow) between member(adhérent) and copy(exemplaire), imean a member borrows a copy then we should test if it's ok, isn't there another way to separate borrowable documents from the others ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not two classes: Book and Review. (Please tell to your teacher that's it is better to use english for class name and to avoid accent: i never see classes names with accent in code)

I would change the orientation of the association betweem Copy and Document. I understood that's Document is the official reference of a document. It's could be a normalized one and could be the same in all librairies in the world: its role is not to manage Copies.

You get a lot's of classes without neither attribute nor method: they could be replaced by a simple enumeration.

Then the following model shows that a user can borrow books only. This solution avoid OCL usage.  Even if OCL could be a good ideas: it simplifies the model but adds the complexity of OCL rule.

[image: class diagram of library]

Comment: hey @granier for the classes that have no attributes and method, it's just that i stoppoed developping my diagram class sine i got stuck in the document/copy issue, i really wanted to avoid making borrowableCopy and unborrowableCopy classes but i guess there's no other way around it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
public class Document
{
    //document properties
}
public interface IBorrowable
{
    Document Lend();
}

public class Book : Document, IBorrowable
{
    public Document Lend()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Review:Document
{

}
```

I think this way makes a good amount of sense, as being able to be borrowed is an ability, specific kinds of documents can own.

Another reason that this way will be dynamic enough to cover other future types of documents you might need.

[image: class diagram]

Comment: The solution isn't wrong, but it's not UML. You need to show that with a constraint linked to the association.

Comment: yes as you may have noticed i already have a an interface borrowable(empruntable) in my class diagram, i had book implements my interface but the assocition borrow is between copy and member so, so a member can call the method to borrow of any  documents's copy.

Comment: @ThomasKilian you mean with OCL ? is that going to appear in my class diagram ?

Comment: sorry, I do not  know french so the diagram is not that clear to me, the thing is if a type of document can not be borrowed then it should not implement IBorrowable

Comment: @YahyaHussein the issue here is, it's not the book that should be borrowed but the copy of it because a book has multiple copies available and that copy class is a common thing between review and book :/

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by copy? it seems like an instance of Book or review to me

Comment: @KarimBenfaida You can use OCL or simply plain text for a constraint. I go with the latter since that can be read by anyone while the OCL community is still more university oriented. And yes, it appears as a note with the constraint in curly brackets.